# Were Cara's victims in “Long Live the King” targets of opportunity, or were they picked on purpose (and by whom)?

Tags: being-human

In [*Being Human*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1349938/) (the original British series) season 2 [episode 3 “Long Live the King”](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1533181/), [Cara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Being_Human_characters#Series_2) kills some teenagers after [Mitchell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Being_Human_characters#John_Mitchell) has ordered that there should be no killing of humans. The teenagers are apparently an opportunistic target: we see Cara seeming to fancy them in a mall, and Cara isn't the subtle type. Yet [Chief constable Wilson](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0224307/) implies to Mitchell in one of their confrontations that the victims were targeted as they all had prior run-ins with the police. So was this just a coincidence that Wilson does not believe in, was there some deeper plot that Mitchell failed to uncover, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

First let me say, I was attempting to clean my house while I was watching this episode, so I certainly wouldn't take my interpretation of this as gospel.  However, I too was a little intrigued by this particular scene and I re-watched it.

I was under the impression that Cara's hunger was completely out of control by this point.  I recall she observed the teenagers at the mall, and they appeared to be bullying another girl (playing keep-away with the girl's purse or something to that effect).  Just from Cara's appearance, it seems to me that she was probably a girl who was bullied/picked on before she became a vamp.

Then the scene changes and you see her killing one girl, but she walks away and leaves the other unharmed (possibly the girl who was being bullied?  I'm not 100% sure).  It just seemed more personal than random to me, but maybe I'm overthinking it.